# É possível importar uma lib .so x32 usando um arm7l (Raspberry Pi 3b)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação para rodar em um raspberry pi 3 mas enquanto o correio não entregava comecei no notebook(Linux Mint) e não tive muitos problemas.

Quando recebi a raspberry testei a aplicação mas não consegui importar a lib do leitor biometrico fornecida pelo fabricante (CIS), aparecei o erro "invalid ELF header"

[print do erro + arquitetura](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/2262/eR296X.png)

É possível de alguma forma importar uma lib .so x32 em um linux arm ?

obs.: estava usando o Ubuntu Mate

Comment: Marcos, sinto não ter maiores detalhes, mas sim, é possível importar `shared objects` na plataforma. Leia mais sobre [arquivos ELF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELF), pode te dar uma luz. Creio que seja só uma questão de alvo de compilação, possivelmente [no Raspberry seja ARM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)

Comment: Talvez seja porque está tentando importar uma lib x32 numa arquitetura x64. Tentou recompilar em x64?

Comment: @CarlosAndrade no print o primeiro erro é eu tentando importa a x32 o segundo é eu tentando importar o x64 a lib do fabricante ja vem compilada, é possível editar um .so ? se for talvez funcione

Comment: Eu acredito que não, você terá que solicitar para o fabricante a versão para x64.